# Square units of area in a circle

Tags: geometry

I'm studying for the GRE and came across the practice question quoted below. I'm having a hard time understanding the meaning of the words they're using. Could someone help me parse their language?

> "The number of square units in the area of a circle '$X$' is equal to $16$ times the number of units in its circumference. What are the diameters of circles that could fit completely inside circle $X$?"

For reference, the answer is $64$, and the "explanation" is based on $\pi r^2 = 16(2\pi r).$

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the diameter be $d$. Then the number of square units in the area of the circle is $(\pi/4)d^2$. This is $16\pi d$. That forces $d=64$.

**Remark:** Silly problem: it is unreasonable to have a numerical equality between area and circumference. Units don't match, the result has no geometric significance.
"The number of square units in the area of" is a fancy way of saying "the area of."

Comment: Thanks for responding. Is a "square unit" the same as "area of"? Or is it a square circumscribed in a circle? Where are you getting (π/4)d2 ?

Comment: The area of a circle of radius $r$ is, as you mentioned, $\pi r^2$. So the area of a circle of diameter $d$ is $\pi(d/2)^2$, We coudld have instead worked with $r$, and translated to diameter at the end.  Yes, "the number of square units in the area of" is a fancy way of saying "the area of."

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Of course, the phrasing "the number of square units in the area of" (and "the number of [linear] units") isn't just to be fancy; it's *specifically* to address your objection that units of length and area don't match, saying, in effect, "We know *that*. This isn't about units. Just make the *numbers* equal to each other." This is a *perfectly* reasonable algebraic exercise. Apples aren't oranges, either, but we can certainly compare *numbers* of each.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing this, and how I see the problem is:

$πr^2 = (2πr) * 16 $

If you solve this, r gives $32$, and since diameter $d = 2*r$, $d = 64$.

So, any circle with a lesser diameter fits in this circle $(d<64)$